# java create name of file with object sending a pattern

Tags: java, string, format

I am working with external configuration files, such as an application.yml in Springboot, the program copied files and renamed the files, but if I need another pattern the name of the files thengo to change in code.

Let's suppose the following code:

```
public class Pet {

private chain name;
private rope bread;
private chain size;
PrivateVar private chain;

Getters and Setters ....

}
```

And I make the name of the files with this code:

```
Pet pet = getPet();
String fileName = String.format ("% s_% s_% s_% s", pet.getName (), pet.getBread (), pet.getSize (), pet.getOtherVar ());
```

This is the problem, it is not dynamic.

In my configuration file, I think, I can write the pattern and send an object as input and have the patron organize the name.

```
String.format (pattern_from_the_file_config, pet);
```

Can I do this or is there any way to do this?

Comment: don't you think it would be a good idea if the configuration file's file name have a unique naming scheme so your program can distinguish between a config file and just a normal file??

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a method (Pet's in this example) to specify and return filename.

If it's still too hardcoded for you, maybe *reflections* may help.

[Java Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

But it's really not recommended, dangerous and should be used only if necessary. Think twice before you'll use it. By doing that, you are losing control of code correctness (for example if you made mistake by typing wrong class field/method name in your configuration file).

Answer (score 1):

Why you just don't simply override the ToString() method?

According to your example:

```
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return String.format ("% s_% s_% s_% s", pet.getName (), pet.getBread (), pet.getSize (), pet.getOtherVar ());
  }
```

this will change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As Peteef mentioned such trick would require **Java Reflection API** usage. If you aware about potential problems, consider following code snippet:

```
//...
    String fileName = getFileName(classNameFromConfigFile);
//...

String getFileName(String className) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
    StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String nameSeparator = "_";
    for(Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
        nameBuilder.append(nameSeparator).append(field.getName());
    }
    return nameBuilder.toString();
  }
```